# How to programatically create a Cloud Run service from Node.js?

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-cloud-run

I'm trying to create a new Cloud Run service from firebase functions using the `googleapis` client library. The following code:

```
  const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    projectId,
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']
  });
  const authClient = await auth.getClient();

  const result = await google.run({
    version: 'v1',
    auth: authClient
  }).namespaces.services.create({
    parent: `namespaces/${projectId}`,
    requestBody: {
      metadata: {
        name: 'asdf'
      },
      spec: {
        template: {
          spec: {
            containers: [
              {
                image: 'gcr.io/graph-4d1ec/graph@sha256:80c764961657d7e2fe548b3886c4662c55c9b5ac881aad5a74cce2d1f97895b8',
                env: [
                  { name: 'URL', value: url }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        traffic: [{ percent: 100, latestRevision: true }]
      }
    }
  }, {})
```

Produces an error:

```
Error: The request has errors
    at Gaxios._request (/srv/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:85:23)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

No further information is provided as to what is wrong with this request.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Most notably, the API client library you're using by default points to `run.googleapis.com`.

However, while using `namespaces.services.create`, you need a regional api endpoint, such as `us-central1-run.googleapis.com`. I'm not familiar with Node.js but you need to change the API endpoint from the default to this value.

You are in super luck, I just published a blog post several 5 minutes ago explaining how does `gcloud run deploy` work under the covers, with details on API calls, how updates are made etc. https://ahmet.im/blog/gcloud-run-deploy/ It has sample Go code linked at the end that you can study. Note that "updating" Cloud Run services has several other intricacies to understand, so make sure to check out the blog post.

Furthermore, to debug the issue you are having, I'm assuming (again I know nothing about Node.js) you might find more info in the `result` object that storing some error value or http response code or body.

Comment: I tried setting `await google.run({..., rootUrl: 'us-central1-run.googleapis.com'})`, which from looking at the code of the library seems to be the correct param, but now I'm getting `404 Not Found`.

Comment: I think you need https://, and potentially a trailing `/`. Can you please insert a `mitmproxy` in the middle and set https_proxy env var for your app to capture the traffic from your app? That, combined with my blog post can help you debug. Since you're directly using API calls, you can't expect too much forgiveness, everything has to be exact.

Comment: yeah, sorry forgot to add `https://` in my comment, but I actually tried it with it.

Comment: I also tried to copy the request `gcloud --log-http run deploy ...` makes, still same problem.

Comment: What’s the error message from the request you copied? As I said, I have reimplemented this in Go and have sample code public. I recommend you study it.